# Matlab addtodate function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use "addtodate" function of matlab. Am I correct in observing that it can't be applied to vector of dates ?

If that is the case how do I add an hour to each of the dates in the following vector of dates:

```
stDt = datenum('2/28/2014');
endDt = datenum('4/29/2014');
interval = (datenum(1987,0,0,1,0,0)-datenum(1987,0,0,0,0,0));
z1 = datenum(stDt):interval:datenum(endDt);
z = datestr(addtodate(z1,1,'hour'));
```

The last line fails with following error:

```
??? Error using ==> addtodate at 42
Date number must be a numeric scalar.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`datenum` in matlab returns a serial date number in units of days. To add an hour to each date in a vector just add `1/24`:

```
z = datestr(z1 + 1/24);
```